# Building legacy Turbo C++ Code

Tags: c++, porting, legacy-code, turbo-c++

I am looking to revive some old C++ code, developed in Turbo C++ for DOS. It's a console-based text game.

This app makes heavy use of conio.h - the Turbo C-specific functions (I think) gotoxy(), window() and the like.

I find that Turbo C++ compiler is no longer available for download. Embarcardero/CodeGear/Borland seem to have removed it completely from their sites.

I need to hack together a new prototype based on the legacy app; most of the functionality is present in the old app and would be too much to rewrite (using a library like ncurses which offers similar functionality). I plan to port the application only later, after a demo, to a modern compiler.

How would you suggest I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to build the app using C++ Builder trial edition. It does not 
I had to make a new project file though.
There is still support for conio.h in C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to look up ncurses to get this functionality.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses
- http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Comment: is there no plug and play alternative? have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Someone has written a copy of that file for an open source compiler [Borland-style CONIO implementation for MinGW/Dev-C++.](http://conio.sourceforge.net/), might be worth taking a look at.